# glReadPixel will return garbage on Adreno 2XX GPU if FBO size less than 16x16

Tags: android, gpu, fbo

Any one experienced the similar issues?

If I create a bigger FBO(say 17x17), draw the small one onto it, and then try glReadPixel with the new FBO, I can get the correct result. Is this a known issue of Adreno 2XX? Bug of TBR with FBO smaller than a single tile(16x16)?

Even weirder, on HTC One S and Xiaomi (Adreno 2XX) not only glReadPixel is buggy, any glDrawElement/Array is not working properly on FBO with size less than 17x17.

btw, Multisampling is off.